PDF : Adding an image stream (self made API)
I am currently making my own API for a PDF creation tool, using the ISO SPEC, from scratch. The intent is to create some PDF by code. So far it is going good. I can create pages, text, boxes,... the last thing I need to implement is the possibility to add some images. Here is what I've got so far :
%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R >> endobj
2 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [ 4 0 R ] /Count 1 >> endobj
3 0 obj << /Length 37 >> stream
q 403 0 0 115 36 200 cm /Im1 Do Q
endstream endobj
4 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Contents 3 0 R /Resources << /XObject << /Im1 5 0 R >> >> >> endobj
5 0 obj << /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /Height 115 /Subtype /Image /Type /XObject /Width 403 /BitsPerComponent 8 /Length 14079 >> 
stream

....[image stream]....
endstream endobj
xref
0 6
0000000000 65535 f
0000000010 00000 n
0000000060 00000 n
0000000120 00000 n
0000000206 00000 n
0000000337 00000 n
trailer
<< /Size 6 /Root 1 0 R >>
startxref
14567
%%EOF

After inspecting some existing PDF documents, I'm pretty sure this is close to working. However, AcrobatReader won't open my document, and opening it with Edge displays the document, but the image is funcky.
For the stream itself I use :
Dim byteStream As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\---------------\Images\test.JFIF")
Then -> $"stream {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteStream)} endstream"

Clearly I'm missing something here. Has somebody any hint ?
Thank you & kind regards,
FINET L.
SPEC, Internet, Forums, ..

Can you share the actual PDF, so we can check what is wrong?

This sequence is your problem: {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteStream)}. You have to write the actual bytes, not their string representation as the byte to string conversion will damage the data.

@iPDFdev This was my first thought when I woke up this morning & this is indeed the case. Putting the raw data fixed it all... Tunnel vision got me there.. :)

The filter mentioned by @kj also is relevant. Without it your PDF may show in some viewers (which recognize and fix the error under the hood) but not in others.

The program fail is there is a missing parameter for decoding.
All the instructions around the image will at runtime support an image window of
X = 403 x Y = 115 (46345 pixels)
The image is defined to be rendered as simple RGB thus run time bytes, when uncompressed, will be 139035 bytes.
However the resource is declared as /Length 14079  clearly indicating compression.
You indicate in question a JFIF tag which should thus be using DCT compression,
but you have not used that flag!!
If using an uncompressed BLOB it will look like this

6 0 obj <</BitsPerComponent 8/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Width 3/Height 3/Length  27/Subtype/Image>>
stream
ÿ   ÿ   ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿÿÿ    ÿÿÿ   
endstream
endobj

As a larger JPEG compressed image, that will be much bigger than 27 bytes, but smaller than any other format. Above image compressed as JPEG = 5,235 bytes.
Degraded by a library that will look like this inferior 95% = 4083 bytes. Which was why above, I wrote it manually (or with computer aid) as only 27 pixel  ANSI 100% perfect characters.
6 0 obj
<</Width 147/Height 147/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/BitsPerComponent 8/Subtype/Image/Type/XObject/Filter/DCTDecode/Length 4083>>stream
ÿØÿà JFIF  ` `  ÿÛ C ...etc...

We could of course use a 100% Quality Subpixel OFF 3x3 image but the smallest will still be 485 Bytes compared to 27 raw bytes!
Answer
When adding the smallest compressed JPEG images they need to be declared first as:
/Filter/DCTDecode

Or otherwise as say zip compression = /Filter/FlateDecode etc.
Actually best compressed method (in the above example) as the overhead is 2 bytes so 29/27 % bigger.
6 0 obj
<</BitsPerComponent 8/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Filter/FlateDecode/Height 3/Length 29/Subtype/Image/Type/XObject/Width 3>>stream
xœûÏÈÊðŸˆÿÿÿÏðˆ™ÁL ¨V 
endstream
endobj


A related digression about ANSI text image conversion to PDF is that on Windows a very fast method is using ANSI in JScript (the only character you need to avoid is "Pure Black" = NUL or 00 in Hexadecimal)
var ByteStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
ByteStream.Type = 2; // Writer
ByteStream.Charset = "Windows-1252"; //Best for PDF writer
var BS = ByteStream; // Abreviate for ease of edit
BS.Open();
BS.Position = 0;

BS.WriteText("%PDF-1.0\n");
BS.WriteText("%ÅÑ§¡\n");

BS.WriteText("1 0 obj <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>> endobj\n");
BS.WriteText("2 0 obj <</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>> endobj\n");
BS.WriteText("3 0 obj <</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 144 144]/Rotate 0/Resources<</XObject<</Img0 4 0 R>>>>/Contents 5 0 R/Parent 2 0 R>> endobj\n");
BS.WriteText("4 0 obj <</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Height 25/Width 24/BitsPerComponent 1/Length 75/ColorSpace[/Indexed/DeviceRGB 1<0000FFFFFFFF>]>> stream\n");
BS.WriteText('ÿÿÿÿÿÿÀmß[}ÑoEÑ[EÑqEßE}ÀUÿñÿÁ«Á¬ÛZcýÖÇÈ"}ÿÕïÀMsß`§Ñ]9ÑNÑE·ßLÇÀA[ÿÿÿÿÿÿ');
BS.WriteText("\nendstream\nendobj\n");
var Pos1 = "000000000"+BS.Position
BS.WriteText("5 0 obj <</Length 101>> stream\n");
BS.WriteText("q\n1 0 0 -1 18 54 cm\n35 0 0 -36 0 36 cm\n/Img0 Do\nQ\nq\n1 0 0 -1 71 144 cm\n70 0 0 -72 0 72 cm\n/Img0 Do\nQ\n");
BS.WriteText("\nendstream\nendobj\n\n");
var Pos2 = BS.Position
BS.WriteText("xref\n0 6\n");
BS.WriteText("0000000000 00001 f \n0000000015 00000 n \n0000000060 00000 n \n0000000111 00000 n \n0000000237 00000 n \n"+Pos1.slice(-10)+" 00000 n \n");
BS.WriteText("\ntrailer\n<</Size 6/Info<</Producer(JScrip2pdf)>>/Root 1 0 R>>\nstartxref\n"+Pos2+"\n%%EOF\n");

BS.SaveToFile("HelloWorld-Blue&W.pdf", 2);
BS.Close();

Will on double click produce this PDF.

